# Defining a pointer to a function that has an absolute address - C

Tags: c, function, pointers, macros

I have the following function calls:

```
((int(*)(const char *format, ...))0x0000ab8c)(format, p2)
```

and

```
int printf2(const char *format, ...)(format, p2)
```

I sometimes use the first function, and sometimes the second one, and therefore would like to define a macro that defines both functions but selects one of the definitions according to a boolean definition

```
#ifdef FIRST
   #define print_function(format, ...)     ((int(*)(const char *format, ...))0x0000ab8c)(format, __VA_ARGS__)
#else
   #define print_function(format, ...)     printf2(format, __VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

Moreover, I would like to pass those functions as a parameter to another function. Is there any generic solution that could work here?

Comment: What do you mean by "generic"? What's wrong  with the way you have shown?

Comment: _Generic_ --> no, as there is no generic (portable) way to convert an arbitrary function address to an absolute address.  Yet in this case a `union` of the 2 function pointers along with a `bool` in a `struct` would work.  IAC, why not call a _function_ with `(bool, format, p2, ...)` rather than a macro?

Comment: @chux +1 for mentioning unions.